# How can I traverse directories named in Japanese in Python?

Tags: python, ios, unicode, character-encoding, internationalization

I'm trying to build a simple helper utility that will look through my projects and find and return the open ones to me via command line. But my calls to `os.listdir` return gibberish (example: `'\x82\xa9\x82\xcc\x96I'`) whenever the folder or filename is in Japanese, and said gibberish can't be passed to the call again to get into the folder either. i.e. `os.listdir('C:\Documents and Settings\\x82\xa9\x82\xcc\x96I')` returns an error:

```
'WindowsError: [Error 3] 指定されたパスが見つかりません。'
```

Does anybody know how I can get around this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: 指定されたパスが見つかりません。 means "Cannot find the path specified."

Comment: Thank you! Actually, reading the Japanese is no problem for me, but I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to decode the string into Unicode, then re-encode it in UTF-8 before passing it to `os.listdir`. It looks like your Japanese string is encoded in shift-JIS:

```
>>> '\x82\xa9\x82\xcc\x96I'.decode('shift-jis').encode('utf-8')
'\xe3\x81\x8b\xe3\x81\xae\xe8\x9c\x82'
>>> print '\x82\xa9\x82\xcc\x96I'.decode('shift-jis')
かの蜂
```

Alternatively, make use of the following feature of [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) to get Unicode strings out of it in the first place:

> On Windows NT/2k/XP and Unix, if *path* is a Unicode object, the result will be a list of Unicode objects. Undecodable filenames will still be returned as string objects.

So:

```
os.listdir(ur'C:\Documents and Settings')
# ---------^
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try to pass in the directory-name as Unicode-literal (`u'your/path'`). This way, the result is also Unicode (which is probably required to work with Japanese characters).

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir):

> On Windows NT/2k/XP and Unix, if path is a Unicode object, the result
>   will be a list of Unicode objects. Undecodable filenames will still be
>   returned as string objects.